# Adding border and border colour to TITLES in mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have titles in Mapbox which are black, Is there any possibility that I can add white borders to it. I have tried a lot of things (fill outline colour etc.) and it didn't work out.

```
  map.addLayer({

    'id': layerID, // changing here gives the description
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': 'places',
         
        'layout': {
        'text-field'  : ['get', 'title'],
        'text-offset' : [0, 1.25],
        'text-anchor' : 'top',
        "text-font"   : ["DIN Offc Pro Medium", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
        
            'icon-image': 'myimage',
            'icon-allow-overlap': true,
            "text-size": 20,
            
            
        },
        
    
        "paint": {
            "text-color": "black",
        
            },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "halo", you may control it with the following `paint` properties:

```
"paint": {
    "text-color": "black",
    "text-halo-color": "white",
    "text-halo-width": 2,
    "text-halo-blur": 1
}
```

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-symbol-text-halo-width

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-symbol-text-halo-color

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-symbol-text-halo-blur